# Почему не возвращаются значения text() и styleSheet()?

Tags: python, sqlite

Пишу код на Python и SQLite и тут возникает проблема: значения text() и styleSheet() возвращаются как "None", хотя и текст и таблица стилей есть. Из-за чего возникает проблема и как ее можно решить? Заранее спасибо.

```
    def load(self):
        cur = self.con.cursor()
        sql = '''INSERT INTO Задачи(Название, label, Текст, Статус, Дата, LCD, Время, kol, kol_1, kol_2) 
        VALUES(?, ?, ?,
        ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) '''
        rezult = cur.execute(sql, ("self.widget_{}".format(self.i),
                                   'self.label_{}'.format(self.i),
                                   str(exec('self.label_{}.text()'.format(self.i))),
                                   str(exec("self.widget_{}.styleSheet()".format(self.i))),
                                   str(self.date),
                                   'self.lcdNumber_{}'.format(self.i),
                                   "{}:{}".format(self.t.hour(), self.t.minute()),
                                   str(self.kol),
                                   str(self.kol_1),
                                   str(self.kol_2)))
        self.con.commit()
```

Comment: Кст, `str(` там будет излишним, т.к. text и styleSheet и так вернут строку. И вместо `format` можно использовать f-строки, например: `f'self.label_{self.i}.text()'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вместо `exec` используйте `eval`:

```
eval('self.label_{}.text()'.format(self.i))
```

и

```
eval("self.widget_{}.styleSheet()".format(self.i))
```

---

Но лучше не использовать `eval`/`exec`, а честно поместить виджеты в списки (или другие коллекции) и работать с ними через цикл